# onMouse event with nested React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a React component that allows highlighting the hovered component when the mouse is over it.  I will have nested versions of these components, so when the mouse is over the outer component I want to put a border around the outer component and all of its children, but once the mouse moves over a child component I only want the border around the child component and it's children, but not the parent component.

I created a simple fiddle to highlight problem.  It is very inconsistent.  At times it works, but other times it draws the border around both components or none.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
             <Hover name={'Outer Component Hover'}>
               <Hover  name={'Inner Component Hover'}/>
             </Hover>
           </div>;
  }
}

class Hover extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { draggable: false };
  }

  mouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({ draggable: true });
  }
  mouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({ draggable: false });
  }
  render() {
    var cls = this.state.draggable ? 'over' :'none';
  
    return (
    <div className={cls} onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter} onMouseOut={this.mouseLeave}>
    {this.props.name}
    {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.over {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: - you need to use the `context` to tell the children about the parent hover state Or

- you need to tell the children about the parent state through the state, by creating the wrapper component around both.

Comment: you could use a HOC to give the parent the ability to send its children `isHovering` state

Answer (score 1):

In your `Hover` component in your `mouseEnter` you need to use the event that is already being passed. To stop event propagation

```
mouseEnter = event => {
   event.stopPropagation();
   // do rest of the stuff as is
}
```

Basically when 2 event collide this called `bubbling`, you can rad more `event.stopPropagation()` in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: This seems to make things a little more consistent, but not completely.  I can make things even better if I manage a global state with context so child/parent know if the other is selected.  However there still seem to be times when moving the mouse quickly that MouseLeave events are dropped and the state is inconsistent with elements thinking they are still selected.  Any thoughts?